# Position sort order for products in any category not working on Magento 2.4.1-p1

Tags: product-sorting

```
Magento 2.4.1-p1
9 extensions from Amasty
Smartwave Porto theme
```

I just noticed that assigning position numbers to products in any category does not reflect on the front page = it does not sort based on position. I have deleted Cache and reindexed.

[image]

I googled this and apparently, this was an issue in Magento 2.2.7 and also with Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation. I don't believe we have anything from Mageplaza. Would this be caused by extensions from Amasty or our Smartwave Porto theme?

**How to fix it?**

---

Updated on October 13th, 2021:

I just checked and **we do have the following**:

```
MAGEPLAZA EXTENSIONS --> Layered Navigation
```

Is this something that came standard or did I install it?

**How to fix the problem then?**

Porto theme comes with Mageplaza_Layered_Navigation + Mageplaza_Ajax_Layer extensions which interferes with the product sort on category pages.

---

I found the following solution here:

"I am using Porto theme too and had encountered this problem on Magento 2.4.2. After the above comment by @tabunsa, I looked up release notes for mageplaza's layered navigation module and ajax module and realized that they had newer releases that were compatible with 2.4.2 and they fixed the bug. I used composer update mageplaza/* to update the latest 4.1.1 module for layered navigation the issue is now resolved for anyone else who encountered this problem."

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31758

**How do I update the Mageplaza's Layered Navigation module??**

Answer (score 0):

for update the Mageplaza's Layered Navigation module try this on project directory

composer update mageplaza/layered-navigation-m2